# Iterate over array with unknow number of sublevels underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
name: "Peter",
childs: [{
    name: "John",
    childs: [{
        name: "Joseph",
        childs: []
    }]
}]
},
{
    name: "Carl",
    childs: [{
        name: "Sam",
        childs: []
    }]
}]
```

Where each person can have children and each of these children can have any number of children and so on. Does anyone know a good way to perform this on `underscore.js`?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you're asking how to do tree traversal, but not anything unique to underscore.js.  You can do a depth first traversal this way:

```
var children = [{name: "Peter", childs: [...]}, ...]
function traverseAndPrint(tree) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        console.log(tree[i].name);
        traverseAndPrint(tree[i].childs);
    }
}
```

If you need to perform an arbitrary action on each element, you could do the following:

```
function traverseAndCallFunction(tree, functionToCall) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tree.length; i++) {
        functionToCall(tree[i]);
        traverseAndPrint(tree[i].childs);
    }
}
```

where `functionToCall` is a function that takes a child object (according to your example)

I don't see why you'd need underscore.js to do tree traversal.

Comment: Objects do not have a length property. Unless I'm mistaken, the arbitrary object/array nesting pattern wouldn't be traversed by this.

Comment: The root element, and all `childs` elements are arrays.  This isn't just *arbitrary* data, it's *arbitrarily large* data.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted the question. This is not a general solution for tree traversal, but Thiago wasn't asking for that, making this a fine answer.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a more general solution as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was thinking in a solution that I could apply in a underscore.js templating view as I'm migrating the code to Backbone.js. If I can do that, I can "treat" the data before send it to the template. Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I don't know how specifically in underscore, but it seems a simple recursive function would be easy enough for you.

```
var data = [{ 
   name: "Peter",
   childs: [{
       name: "John",
       childs: [{
           name: "Joseph",
           childs: []
       }]
   }, { 
       name: "Carl",
       childs: [{
           name: "Sam",
           childs: []
       }]
   }]
}];

function trav(data, fn) {
    data.forEach(function(item) {
        for (var p in item)
            if (p === "childs")
                trav(item[p], fn);
            else
                fn(item[p], p);
    });
}

trav(data, function(val, prop) {
    console.log(prop, val);
});
```

Comment: I've made a recursive function in the "old code". As I'm passing it all to Backbonejs using the underscore.js templating, I was thinking in a good way to do that on the template. Anyway, thanks for the answer!!!!